# JavaFX DataBinding behaves strange

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx

I have a Worker that fills a result list. A ListView is bound to this result list and gets filled with partial results as soon as they are available. Works great!

Then there is a button that works with items in the list. So it should be disabled as long the list is empty. This works for every other list. But not for this one.

I have reduced the sample by stripping the UI components and just using properties. The result is the same. Either there is some kind of bug or I do not understand how the binding works.

I hope for any helping comments on this.

Just put this code into a main() method and you should see the problem. I am using Java 1.8 Update 74.

```
// a list of items, e.g. in a list view
ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<ObservableList<String>> items = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<>()));

// a button that is disabled if there are no items
BooleanProperty disabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
disabled.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> Boolean.valueOf(items.get().isEmpty()), items));

// a list with results, e.g. from a worker
ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<ObservableList<String>> results = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<>()));
// the items are bound to the results (the list is showing partial result then)
items.bind(results);

// the button is still disabled
System.out.println(disabled.get()); // expected true !WORKS!

// add a result (should inform the items and the button)
results.get().add("Hello");

// both list should be identical now
System.out.println(results.get()); // expected [Hello] !WORKS!
System.out.println(items.get()); // expected [Hello] !WORKS!

// the button should not be disabled anymore
System.out.println(disabled.get()); // expected false !FALIED!

// try to re-bind the button
disabled.unbind();
disabled.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> Boolean.valueOf(items.get().isEmpty()), items));
System.out.println(disabled.get()); // expected false !WORKS!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding is done for `items` and only for `items`. This means the value only gets updated if you replace the list, but not if you just modify it.

To be notified of changes in the list wrapped by `items`, you need to bind the property to the "emptyness condition" of the list every time the list is replaced:

```
items.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)-> {
    if (newValue == null) {
         disabled.unbind();
         disabled.set(true);
    } else {
         disabled.bind(Bindings.isEmpty(newValue));
    }
});
```

or much simpler - use a [`ListProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ListProperty.html):

```
ListProperty<String> items = new SimpleListProperty<>();
disabled.bind(Bindings.isEmpty(items));
```

---

A `Bindings.createXYZBinding(callable, o1, 02, ..., oN)` creates a `XYZBinding` that caches the value returned by `callable` at the time it is evaluated. The evaluation happens lazyly, i.e. when the binding is dirty and:

1. `get` is called on the binding object or
2. the first listener is added to the binding or
3. at least one **`ChangeListener`** was added to the and the binding becomes dirty

The binding is dirty, if

1. The value has not yet been evaluated (initial state)
2. one of the listeners that were added to `o1`, ..., `oN` on creation of the binding receives a change event.

The binding becomes clean (i.e. not dirty) again, if the `callback` is evaluated.

The binding caches the result of the `callback` evaluation and uses this result when `get` is called or when it needs to pass the data to a `ChangeListener`. Listeners are only called, if after a evaluation the value cached changes.

Comment: I did some more testing with your information in mind. Actually the call to `items.bind(results);` in my code changes the value that is wrapped by `items`. You will get a different value if you call `items.get()` before and after. So any binding to the list wrapped by `items` made before is useless. If I do it afterwards, everything works. I did not expect this and still not fully understand why.

Comment: @Future: I added a few lines to the answer. I hope they help you understand and don't confuse you... Basically bindings don't recalculate the value unless they consider it neccesarry based on the events that that occur on the dependencies and `Property`s don't add listeners to the wrapped value, unless it's a special property, like `MapProperty`, `ListProperty` or `SetProperty`